# In Flask is there a way to handle all the type of errors with one error handler & return the type of error occurred?

Tags: python, flask

Is there anyway to handle all the type of error with one definition & return the type of error occurred , For example in the below code error handeller is there for **404** but if I am unaware of other possible errors how can I print the error on html page

```
from flask import Flask, abort
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Welcome to Python Flask."

@app.errorhandler(404) 
def invalid_route(e): 
    return "Invalid route."
```

Expected if possible

```
@app.errorhandler(Type of error) #is there anything I can user here ?
def invalid_route(e): 
    return f"Type of error occurred is {e}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea there are [generic exception handlers](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/errorhandling/#generic-exception-handlers)

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Welcome to Python Flask."


@app.errorhandler(HTTPException)
def handle_exception(e):
    return f'Type of error occurred is {e.code}'

app.run()
```